# Angular 2 Pipe Binding Cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I updated Angular 2 project to Angular 4. I am using Pipe like below.

```
<input  type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="customerSearchText | isnumber" (ngModelChange)="customerSearchText=$event">
```

customerSearchText declaration

```
public customerSearchText: number;
```

isnumber.pipe

```
@Pipe({ name: 'isnumber'})
export class IsNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val: string): any {
    if(!val) return '';
    val=val.toString();
    return WrappedValue.wrap(val.replace(/\D/g, ''))
  }
}
```

When I used like this I am getting error.

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Object]'. Current value: '4'
```

When I deleted pipe from my input, error gone. But I want control  is input number.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: What is `WrappedValue.wrap`?

Comment: Looks like it could be related to this bug: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18129

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening due to the immediate assignment you have with the `(ngModelChange)` event. Try calling a function defined in your component instead of directly doing the assignment in the template for that event, like this,

in template,

```
<input  type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="customerSearchText | isnumber" (ngModelChange)="inputChanged($event)">
```

in your component,

```
inputChanged(value: string): void {
   this.customerSearchText = value;
}
```

Hope it helps.

If it didn't fix, then try wrapping your `''` (empty string) `return` in your pipe with WrappedValue.wrap as in `return WrappedValue.wrap('');`.

Comment: when is the first time you get the error. On page load or after you enter something? Cause the error says the current value is `4`